# Is there any way to add user_id to the File received from react-dropzone?

Tags: file, mongoose, multer, cloudinary, react-dropzone

So I want to add user_id as a property in the file so that I can save the files with specific user_ids. The file is received from the react-dropzone like this with acceptedfiles[0] :

[React Dropzone Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVdLp.png)

Api call that sends the file to the server:
[POST Request from Client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV9HX.png)

I have tried these two methods which are commented:
[Tried methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz3Xr.png)

Route handler:
[Route Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOQnB.png)